# A simple way to register a fake for a concrete class using AutofacContrib.NSubstitute

Tags: autofac, nsubstitute

A class that is resolved as

```
builder.Resolve<IMyInterface>
```

Can be faked like this (for testing)

```
builder.RegisterType<MyFakeClass>().As<IMyInterface>();
```

But what if my class is resolved as

```
builder.Resolve<MyRealClass>
```

How to I fake this in autofac registeration? If I am using AutofacContrib.NSubstitute.
How can I achieve something like this

```
builder.RegisterType<MyFakeClass>().As<MyRealClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as `MyFakeClass` inherits `MyRealClass`, that's all you have to do.